# How to declare an ndarray in cython with a general floating point type

Tags: python, numpy, cython

What is the best way to declare a numpy array in cython if It should be able to handle both float and double?

I guess it won't be possible with a memory view since there the datatype is crucial, but for an ndarray is there any way to give it a general float type which would still benifit from the swiftness of cython?

so this is what I would usualy do:

```
def F( np.ndarray A):
    A += 10
```

I've seen that there is also:

```
def F( np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] A):
    A += 10
```

but that again will give a bit size for the type. I've also thought along the lines of creating a memory view inside the function depending on the bit size (32 or 64).

Any thought are highly appreciated

---

Thank you so much for the tip on the `floating` type. I've tried it like this

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import cython
cimport cython
from libc.math cimport sqrt, abs
from cython cimport floating

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
def Rot_Matrix(np.ndarray[floating, ndim=3] Fit_X,
               np.ndarray[floating, ndim=3] Ref_X,
               weight = None):
    cdef:
        unsigned int t, T = Fit_X.shape[0]
        unsigned int n, N = Fit_X.shape[1]
        np.ndarray[floating, ndim=3] Rot = np.empty((T,3,3))

    return Rot
```

when I now call the function with two arrays of np.float32 I get the error

> ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'float' but got 'double'

If I do not use the the type definition in the brakes for `Rot` so it reads `np.ndarray[floating, ndim=3] Rot = np.empty((T,3,3))` then I get ndarray back and it works fine. Would you happen to have a pointer for me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I doubt you can mix native types of different sizes, it would blow the performance.

Comment: So you would just leave it as I did in the first example? Would it help to declare the number of dimensions though?

Comment: @Magellan88 I just saw the update to your post. I've updated my response.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well this is actually really easy with fused types support:

> *This goes inside your code.*

```
from cython cimport floating

def cythonfloating_memoryview(floating[:, :] array):
    cdef int i, j

    for i in range(array.shape[0]):
        for j in range(array.shape[1]):
            array[i, j] += 10
```

Of course, there are loads of ways of doing this:

> *Name this **fuzed.pyx**. There's no need to compile or run `cython` on it; it's handled by `pyximport`. Don't use `pyximport` for production code, though, as you should typically only ship `.c` files.*

```
from cython cimport floating
from numpy import float32_t, float64_t, ndarray

ctypedef fused myfloating:
    float32_t
    float64_t

def cythonfloating_memoryview(floating[:, :] array):
    # ...

def cythonfloating_buffer(ndarray[floating, ndim=2] array):
    # ...

def myfloating_memoryview(myfloating[:, :] array):
    # ...

def myfloating_buffer(ndarray[myfloating, ndim=2] array):
    # ...
```

and here's a little test script:

> *Name this **test.py** and run it as a normal Python script:*

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()

import fuzed
import numpy

functions = [
    fuzed.cythonfloating_memoryview,
    fuzed.cythonfloating_buffer,
    fuzed.myfloating_memoryview,
    fuzed.myfloating_buffer,
]

for function in functions:
    floats_32 = numpy.zeros((100, 100), "float32")
    doubles_32 = numpy.zeros((100, 100), "float64")

    function(floats_32)
    function(doubles_32)

    print(repr(floats_32))
    print(repr(doubles_32))
```

---

It's worth noting that fused types are specialised at compilation, and are constant for a particular function invocation. The empty Numpy array you make is always of a `double` type, but you assign it to either a 32-bit float or a 64-bit float. Here's what you should do:

```
from cython cimport floating
import numpy

def do_some_things(floating[:] input):
    cdef floating[:] output

    if floating is float:
        output = numpy.empty(10, dtype="float32")
    elif floating is double:
        output = numpy.empty(10, dtype="float64")
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unknown floating type.")

    return output
```

and some tests to prove the point:

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
#>>> (None, None)

import floatingtest
import numpy

floatingtest.do_some_things(numpy.empty(10, dtype="float32"))
#>>> <MemoryView of 'ndarray' at 0x7f0a514b3d88>
floatingtest.do_some_things(numpy.empty(10, dtype="float32")).itemsize
#>>> 4

floatingtest.do_some_things(numpy.empty(10, dtype="float64"))
#>>> <MemoryView of 'ndarray' at 0x7f0a514b3d88>
floatingtest.do_some_things(numpy.empty(10, dtype="float64")).itemsize
#>>> 8
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the test script, I'm not really sure how to use it. I've managed to compile it into a test.o file but there is no function in there to import. I've tried to import the list by doing `from test import functions` but that won't work. I hope that's not too stupid of a question

Comment: The test script is just a Python file; `fuzed` is the name of the second block of code. I'll update the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Fused types can only be used in function declarations. The best analogy I can come up with are templates in C++.

To create a function that can be used with float32/64 do

```
from cython import floating, numeric
cimport cython

def func_float(floating a):
    print cython.typeof(a)
```

however you can only used `Fused Types` in a function that already appear in the function declaration.

Comment: AFAICT this isn't true... yet you have more votes than me. \*cries\* ;)

Comment: yeah I realized a bit later that I got compilation errors because cython only handles the fused types that are used in the function declaration.  `def f(numeric a): cdef floating v` will result in a compilation error as well as `def f(double a): cdef floating v`